# How to replace a node by a ruby string?

Tags: ruby, hpricot

I'm trying to replace all my `<img>` tags in an HTML file by `<%= image_tag() %>` rails tag.

What I want to do is something like:

```
doc = open("myfile.html") { |f| Hpricot(f) }
imgs = doc.search("//img") # here i got all Hpricot::Elements

imgs.each { |i|
  # fake function name !
  i.replace_by_HTML('<%= image_tag("/images/blabla.jpg") %>')
}
```

What I need it a function that will replace the node in the file by a string I would pass.

```
< img src="/images/blalba.jpg" /> would give => <%= image_tag("/images/blabla.jpg") %>
```

#### Update:

I don't really want to use regular expressions, thats why I choosed Hpricot, because it will parse the HTML for me and then I can do `Element.attributes` and generate my `image_tag` with all the attributes included.

What if my img tags are like:

```
< img style="float:left;" src="images/blabla.jpg" width="30" height="30" ... />
```

or

```
< img src=\"images/blabla.jpg\" style=\"float:left;\" width=\"30\" height=\"30\" ... />
```

See what I mean? I may parse a .SQL file containing escaping slashes, the `src` attribute could be after another attribute, etc ...

The thing is I already did the function that will return my an `image_tag` if i give an `Hpricot::Element`, but I don't know how to replace the original node by my string in the Hpricot doc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with gsub string method and regular expresions

```
doc = open("myfile.html") { |f| 
  f.read().gsub(/<img src="([^"]*)".*\/>/, '<%= image_tag("\1") %>') 
}
```

I don't have hpricot installed but it seems (check this [hpricot-altering](http://wiki.github.com/hpricot/hpricot/hpricot-altering)) that you coud use swap method on searched elements

```
imgs.each { |i|
  i.swap('<%= image_tag(' + i.src + ') %>')
}
```